# which of the following is/are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $W \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a linear subspace of dimension at most $n-1$.

then

1) $W$ is nowhere dense

2) $W$ is closed

3) $\mathbb R^n\setminus W$ is connected.

4) $\mathbb R^n\setminus W$ is not connected.

i am thinking above in the way that $W$ should be isomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$ where $k$ is atmost $n-1$. then answer should be $2$ and $3$. am right?

Comment: 2 is correct, but not 3: take $n=2$ and $W$ of dimension $1$.

Comment: You are correct on 1) and 2) [can you prove it?]. For 3) and 4), it might help to think about a low dimensional example e.g. $W \subset \mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 1):

Think of a line in the plane. If you remove it, we get two pieces. Same with a plane in 3-space. But removing a line in 3-space leaves a connected space. So 3 and 4 don't **always** hold, so are false in general.

1 and 2 do hold. Any open ball is $n$-dimensional.

Comment: any reason for 1) AND 2)?

Comment: Closedness should be clear. The reason for 2 I did write down, interior is empty is enough to see nowhere denseness